# What are ASCII 17-20?

Tags: ascii

In the ASCII table, entries for # 17-20 are listed as (device control 1-4).

What is the purpose of these characters? Do they have any specific meaning, or are they just extra characters?

Comment: Tons of information on this from a quick Google search.

Comment: [ASCII control characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Control_characters)

Comment: [to get a more succinct definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes#Device_control)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They have a specific meaning according to the [norm](https://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/chars/c0.html), they are :

> A device control character which is primarily intended for turning on
>   or starting an ancillary device. If it is not required for this
>   purpose, it may be used to restore a device to the basic mode of
>   operation (see also DC2 and DC3), or for any other device control
>   function not provided by other DCs.

For an historical perspective, you can read the original [American Standard Code for Information Interchange](https://web.archive.org/web/20020112110814/http://www.wps.com/texts/codes/X3.4-1963/index.html) approved the June 17, 1963.